# Type Mismatch (for a custom type)

Tags: functional-programming, elm

I think the code is a better representation of the problem vs me explaining it with regular english.

This is the code for domain modelling:

```
module Domain.A exposing (..)

import Domain.B

type Size
  = Pound Float
  | Kilogram Float
  | Gram Float
  | Liter Float
  | Ounce Float
  | Count Int

type StockStatus 
  = InStock
  | OutOfStock

type alias CityWholesalerProduct =
  {
    cityWholesalerId : String,
    brand : String,
    productSku : Maybe String,
    sku : String,
    upc : Maybe String,
    description : String,
    status : StockStatus,
    price : Float,
    unit : Domain.B.Unit,
    pack : Int,
    size : Size
  }
```

and this is the code for the model inside Main.elm

```
-- MODEL

type alias Model =
  { cityWholesalerProducts : (List Domain.A.CityWholesalerProduct)
  , cityWholesalerProduct : Domain.A.CityWholesalerProduct
  }

init : Model
init = 
  Model 
    [] 
    {
      cityWholesalerId = "",
      brand = "",
      productSku = "",
      sku = "",
      upc = "",
      description = "",
      status = Domain.A.OutOfStock,
      price = 0.00,
      unit = Domain.B.Count,
      pack = 0,
      size = Domain.A.Count 0
    }
```

The problem is that I'm getting an error that says:

```
TYPE MISMATCH - The 2nd argument to `Model` is not what I expect:

34|   Model 
35|     [] 
36|#>#    {
37|#>#      cityWholesalerId = "",
38|#>#      brand = "",
39|#>#      productSku = "",
40|#>#      sku = "",
41|#>#      upc = "",
42|#>#      description = "",
43|#>#      status = Domain.A.OutOfStock,
44|#>#      price = 0.00,
45|#>#      unit = Domain.B.Count,
46|#>#      pack = 0,
47|#>#      size = Domain.A.Count 0
48|#>#    }

This argument is a record of type:

    { brand : String
    , cityWholesalerId : String
    , description : String
    , pack : Int
    , price : Float
    , productSku : #String#
    , size : Domain.A.Size
    , sku : String
    , status : Domain.A.StockStatus
    , unit : Domain.B.Unit
    , upc : #String#
    }

But `Model` needs the 2nd argument to be:

    #Domain.A.CityWholesalerProduct#

#Hint#: I always figure out the argument types from left to right. If an argument
is acceptable, I assume it is “correct” and move on. So the problem may actually
be in one of the previous arguments!
```

I'm new to Elm and FP in general and type mismatch errors are my biggest pain point and I've been stuck on this one for a while now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm surprised that the Elm compiler - which normally gives really helpful error messages - isn't more specific here. But the problem that I see is simply in those fields - `productSku` and `upc` - where your type alias says they should be of type `Maybe String`, but you have initialised with value `""`, which is simply a `String`.

It's not clear which part is wrong. If those are always supposed to be simple strings, then fix the type declaration, changing `Maybe String` to `String` in those places. But I assume the type declaration is likely as you intended, and the values are wrong. You can try this instead:

```
init = 
  Model 
    [] 
    {
      cityWholesalerId = "",
      brand = "",
      productSku = Just "",
      sku = "",
      upc = Just "",
      description = "",
      status = Domain.A.OutOfStock,
      price = 0.00,
      unit = Domain.B.Count,
      pack = 0,
      size = Domain.A.Count 0
    }
```

which should at least compile - but I can't comment on what the right values are for your intended business logic. It's not clear to me what `Nothing` would signify for these `Maybe` values, and whether that's really any different from `Just ""` - but it could well be that they are.